# Blocking window style changes in AHK/C#

Tags: c#, window, styles, block, autohotkey

I wrote a small autohotkey script that removes the border, titlebar, and resize handles of a window, and centers it on the first monitor. This works for most applications and games, but some (bioshock 2, APB, etc) replace their window style instantly after removing it. Is there a way to block window style changes?

I would prefer to keep this in AHK, but the title has c# in it because I would like to convert my application to that down the road, and if it's only possible in c#/c++ then now would be a good time to start conversion.

Answer (score 0):

I could be missing something, but I doubt this is going to be easy. The behavior you describe is one of an application which is either monitoring for changes in its window style, or just constantly redrawing them nonstop to prevent these changes. Of course you could just Loop through and fight against it where you remove, it replaces, you remove, it replaces, but that won't solve anything.

One way you could try is to create a .dll and inject it into the app's process, and then hook some API calls and simply return before anything gets redrawn. Google for 'detours hooking' for some examples. That *might* work, but would be out of the scope of AHK. And your simple 15 minute AHK script would turn into a much bigger project. =(

Comment: Eh, that would probably set off many different anti-cheat in multiplayer games. I think I may just try setting the visible window region to the client area.